# An error trying to do a conversion from data type bigint to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I've altered a table on my database to add a new column `LogDate`:

```
ALTER TABLE AccountsTable
ADD LogDate bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT(0)
GO
```

Now I've got results in this new column `LogDate` to appear like `1556366669`.

After that I tried to alter my login procedure and added the following code:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[AccountsTable] 
SET LogDate = DATEDIFF(s, '19700101', GETDATE()) 
WHERE AccID = @id

UPDATE [dbo].[AccountsTable]
SET ConsecutiveDays = 
    CASE 
       WHEN CAST(LogDate as Date) = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE) 
                 AND ConsecutiveDays < 3 
          THEN ConsecutiveDays + 1 
       WHEN CAST(LogDate as Date) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) 
          THEN ConsecutiveDays 
       ELSE 1 
    END,
    ChallengesCompleted = 
        CASE 
           WHEN ConsecutiveDays = 3
                AND CAST(LogDate AS DATE) = CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE)
              THEN ChallengesCompleted + 1
           ELSE ChallengesCompleted
        END,
    LogDate = GETDATE()
WHERE 
    AccID = @id
```

And I get the following error trying to alter the login procedure with the code above:

> Explicit conversion from data type bigint to date is not allowed.

Any help is appreciated of what I can do to fix that issue. I am using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Check the answer update, and the discussion (chat) we have started yesterday

Answer (score 1):

### Trying to figure out the issue

The main problem is that you are trying to cast a bigint value to a date which is not allowed.

```
CAST(LogDate as Date)
```

Will throw the following expression:

> Explicit conversion from data type bigint to date is not allowed.

Even if the integer is in the following format `yyyyMMdd` ex: `19700101`

If the integer value is in the following format `yyyyMMdd` you can convert ot string then to date

```
CAST(CAST(LogDate as varchar(25)) as Date)
```

Else you have to implement your own logic. As example if the column contains the second difference with `1970-01-01` you can use:

```
DATEADD(s, [LogDate], '19700101')
```

In addition, using the following expression

```
[LogDate] = GetDATE()
```

will cause the following exception:

> Implicit conversion from data type datetime to bigint is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

You have to change it to

```
[LogDate] = DATEDIFF(s, '19700101', GETDATE())
```

OR

```
[LogDate] = CAST(GETDATE() as BIGINT)
```

It is based on your needs

---

### Date type conversion

From the following Microsoft Grid you can see what data types can be converted with each approach:

[image]

**Reference**

- [Data type conversion (Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017#implicit-and-explicit-conversion)

---

### Update - Fixing the code logic

Based on your comments i think you are looking for the following logic:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[AccountsTable] 
SET LogDate = DATEDIFF(s, '19700101', GETDATE()) 
WHERE AccID = @id AND LogDate IS NULL

UPDATE [dbo].[AccountsTable]
SET ConsecutiveDays = 
    CASE
       WHEN  ConsecutiveDays  > 3 
          THEN 1
       WHEN  CAST(DATEADD(s, [LogDate], '19700101') AS DATE) < CAST(DATEADD(d,(-1 * [ConsecutiveDays]),GETDATE()) AS DATE)
          THEN 1
       WHEN  CAST(DATEADD(s, [LogDate], '19700101') AS DATE) < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
          THEN ConsecutiveDays + 1 
       ELSE ConsecutiveDays  
    END,
    ChallengesCompleted = 
        CASE 
           WHEN ConsecutiveDays = 3
           THEN ChallengesCompleted + 1
           ELSE ChallengesCompleted
        END,
    LogDate = DATEDIFF(s, '19700101', GETDATE())
WHERE 
    AccID = @id
```

---

### Update 2 - Based on Chat discussion

Try using the following code:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[AccountsTable] 
SET LogDate = DATEDIFF(s, '19700101', GETDATE()) 
WHERE AccID = @id AND LogDate IS NULL

UPDATE [dbo].[AccountsTable]
SET ConsecutiveDays = 
    CASE
       WHEN  ConsecutiveDays  >= 3 
          THEN 1
       WHEN  CAST(DATEADD(s, [LogDate], '19700101') AS DATE) < CAST(DATEADD(d,(-1 * [ConsecutiveDays]),GETDATE()) AS DATE)
          THEN 1
       WHEN  CAST(DATEADD(s, [LogDate], '19700101') AS DATE) < CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
          THEN ConsecutiveDays + 1 
       ELSE ConsecutiveDays  
    END,
    ChallengesCompleted = 
        CASE 
           WHEN ConsecutiveDays = 2 
                AND CAST(DATEADD(s, [LogDate], '19700101') AS DATE) = CAST(DATEADD(d,(-1 * [ConsecutiveDays]),GETDATE()) AS DATE)
           THEN ChallengesCompleted + 1
           ELSE ChallengesCompleted
        END,
    LogDate = DATEDIFF(s, '19700101', GETDATE())
WHERE 
    AccID = @id
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192499/discussion-on-answer-by-hadi-an-error-trying-to-do-a-conversion-from-data-type-b).